# What is causing black spotting on my air plant?

Tags: houseplants

I've had this tillandsia for about three months now. I watered it yesterday night and left it to dry upside down over night like I normally do. Just this morning I noticed some black spotting on the growing (and hopefully will be blooming) part of my air plant. The spotting is only near the top of the bloom. What is it caused by? can I get rid of it? and will my air plant survive?[image]